# How to process a list and ignore spaces?

Tags: etoolbox, xstring, comma-separated-list

> **This question is part of a new package:**
>   [`metrix`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/metrix). Typeset metric/prosodic symbols standalone and above syllables.

I’m wrinting a new package and I need to process a list (using `etoolbox` at the moment but that can change …). Everything works but I want the list to do two things that don’t work:

1. Ignore spaces, because `xstring` doesn’t get the right strings otherwise.
2. Process an empty list element. It is ignored at the moment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\DeclareListParser{\dolist}{-}
\newcommand{\mylist}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\do}[1]{%
        \IfStrEqCase{##1}{%
            {}{0}%
            {a}{1}%
            {b}{2}%
            {c}{3}%
        }[?]%
    }%
    \dolist{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
    1. \mylist{a-b-c--a}

    2. \mylist{ a- b- c- - a}

    3. \mylist{ a - b  - c  -  - a }
\end{document}
```

The output is

> 1. 1231
> 2. 1231
> 3. ????

but it should be the following in all three cases

> 12301

---

### What I really wan’t to know ;-)

I’m implementing a package to typeset the metrics of (latin) verses, and I’d like to have a macro like

```
\metrics{_    u  u  _   }
        {quid co-me-dent}
```

that renders as

[image: quid comedent]

What I’ve got so far is a macro that works with this syntax

```
\metrics{_-\ -u-u-_}
        {quid-\ -co-me-dent}
```

Obviously there are two differences the space between two words must be separated with hyphen as if it is a syllable and it must be escaped with `\`. It would be great if the first list (the symbols) can be a space separated list and the second on a combination of hyphen and space separated.

You may download my full code from my web site: http://tweh.de/texsx/metrics.tex

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can first replace the space with a special marker, say `-\q_tobi_space_marker-` so you can split at hyphens and have a way to check whether the item was a space. Here's an implementation.

Plan of attack:

1. We change spaces in the way outlined before
2. The two lists are split into sequences
3. The "syllables" sequence is mapped item by item, stepping a counter each time;

   1. if the item is the space marker, step back the counter and issue a space
   2. otherwise use the syllable and put over it the right marker, looking at the "measures" sequence.

The symbol corresponding to the *brevis* or *longa* is obtained by defining two functions `\tobi_u_mark:` and `\tobi___mark:` so we can build it by using the item in the "measures" sequence.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\metrics}{mm}
 {
  \tobi_metrics:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_tobi_words_tl
\seq_new:N \l_tobi_syllables_seq
\seq_new:N \l_tobi_measures_seq
\quark_new:N \q_tobi_space_marker
\int_new:N \l_tobi_process_int

\cs_new_protected:Npn \tobi_metrics:nn #1 #2
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tobi_words_tl { #2 }
  % change spaces into -\q_tobi_space_marker-
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tobi_words_tl { ~ } { - \q_tobi_space_marker - }
  % split the (modified) second argument at -
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_tobi_syllables_seq { - } \l_tobi_words_tl
  % split the first argument "at nothing"
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tobi_measures_seq { } { #1 }
  \int_zero:N \l_tobi_process_int
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tobi_syllables_seq
   {
    \int_incr:N \l_tobi_process_int
    \tl_if_eq:nnTF { ##1 } { \q_tobi_space_marker }
     {% we had a space, step back the counter and issue a space
      \int_add:Nn \l_tobi_process_int { -1 }
      \c_space_token
     }
     {% print the syllable with the metric marker
      \tobi_print_syllable:n { ##1 }
     }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \tobi_print_syllable:n #1
 {% Just a rough approximation, use your method
  \leavevmode\vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \halign{##\cr\hidewidth \tobi_print_meter: \hidewidth \cr #1 \cr}}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \tobi_print_meter:
 {
  \use:c {tobi_\seq_item:Nn \l_tobi_measures_seq { \l_tobi_process_int }_mark:}
 }
\cs_new:Npn \tobi_u_mark: { \Large \u{} }
\cs_new:Npn \tobi___mark: { \Large -- }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\metrics{_    u  u  _   }
        {quid co-me-dent}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Probably one should add some error checks on whether the lengths of the sequences agree. See [How to count the frequency of a token in a token list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124698/4918).

Comment: Thanks. Looks great. Can you tell me a resource where I can learn how to read you code ? ;-) I’m don’t know anything about the L3 syntax …

Comment: @Tobi Start with `texdoc expl3`

Comment: Hm … seems a little complex :-) I got two question: 1. When using this code in a new package, I’d replace the `_tobi`s by `_<packagename>` since I’m building a new module, right? 2. Is it bad practice to mix up L2 and L3 syntax?

Comment: @Tobi I used a "generic" prefix, you should use one more suited to your package. About mixing syntaxes, I'd say that it's preferable to stick to one, but it's not mandatory.

Comment: OK … next question: How can I start to implement a L3 package. Which documentclass can I use to document the package? I know how to use DocStrip with L2 packages but what are the difference in the new version? I found that some packages use `l3doc` but I didn’t found a documentation on that class.

Comment: @Tobi Just look at some packages using L3. I'm not really too much into `l3doc`, so my packages aren't an example. ;-)

Comment: I had a (short) look but unfortunately it’s not that self explaining … || another next question: I tried to replace the marks by my method which is using TikZ, but I get an error, when I replace `\Large\u{}` with a `{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: It works. The problem was that I used the old `arc (1:2:3)` syntax. I guess the `:` caused an error.

Comment: @Tobi Tikz commands should definitely go outside `\ExplSyntaxOn`

Comment: OK thanks. But what is the best way in may case. Defining an “old“ macor (`\newcommand{\mytikz}{...}`) and use this inside of `\cs_new:Npn \metrix_x_mark:`?

Comment: @Tobi Yes, that's the idea.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}

\newcommand{\mylist}[1]{%
  \edef\thestring{#1-}%
  \noblanks[q]{\thestring}%
  \convertword[q]{\thestring}{--}{-0}%
  \convertword[q]{\thestring}{a-}{1}%
  \convertword[q]{\thestring}{b-}{2}%
  \convertword[q]{\thestring}{c-}{3}%
  \convertword{\thestring}{d-}{4}%
}

\begin{document}
    1. \mylist{a-b-c--a}

    2. \mylist{ a- b- c- - a}

    3. \mylist{ a - b  - c  -  - a }
\end{document}
```