# Count number of commas in a list

Tags: latex3

With the following command the tokens can be counted in a list. How can I count only the number of commas in the list?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\CountComma}{m}{%
\tl_count:n {#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\CountComma{1/!/?,2/1/0,3+2/1*2,4/0,5/1/0,6/0,A/B/1,8/0,9/0}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\clist_count:n` instead of `\tl_count:n`, however, it will not count commas that follow right each other, i.e. `\CountComma{1,,,2}` will give `2` and not `3`. It will also not count commas that are inside `{,}`

Comment: And use `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`.

Comment: Slightly related (that one counts number of tokens in a token list): [How to handle a LaTeX3 token list as a list of tokens rather than as a list of items? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393462/how-to-handle-a-latex3-token-list-as-a-list-of-tokens-rather-than-as-a-list-of-i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only a solution for the case that commas do not follow each other without element between or do not occur inside `{}` pairs:

`\clist_count:n` counts the number of elements in a comma separated list, however, `{1,2}` would give `2` instead of `1`, so wrap `\int_eval:n{\clist_count:n {#1} -1}` around this.

Using the hint by egreg: `\int_max:nn {\clist_count:n {#1} -1}{0}` is shorter

Of course the `\CountComma` macro should be expandable, so use `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\CountComma}{m}{% Should be expandable!
    \int_max:nn { \clist_count:n {#1}-1 } {0}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\CountComma{1/!/?,2/1/0,3+2/1*2,4/0,5/1/0,6/0,A/B/1,8/0,9/0}

\CountComma{1,2}

\CountComma{4}

\edef\foo{\CountComma{1,2,3}}

Foo is \foo

\end{document}
```