# How to pass contents of environment (declared with \newenvironment in LaTeX2e) as argument to that environment?

Tags: environments, arguments

I know there's an option in `expl3`, but how can I do the same in LaTeX2e (or TeX)?

```
\newenvironment*{myEnv}[1][]{}{}
\begin{myEnv}
  I first need to pass this to this environment as an argument.
\end{myEnv}
```

Comment: This is what the `environ` package does, the body of the environment is then stored in `\BODY`.

Comment: You can do everything what packages do by copying the contents of these packages in the preamble (sandwiched between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, of course). I do not know what defines an "official" package, but `environ` is definitely a very nice and robust package that gets widely used. The source of the package is not *very* long, so you can have a look at it.

Comment: Example: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{myEnv}[1][]{\underline{\BODY}}
\begin{document}
\begin{myEnv}
  I first need to pass this to this environment as an argument.
\end{myEnv}
\end{document}`

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, for some reason my custom macro can't break down this \BODY parameter, but can break down regular text into letters. In other words \BODY doesn't behave like regular text.

Comment: Well, hard to tell what is going on without seeing your custom macro. You may have to replace `\MyCustomMacro{\BODY}` by `\edef\temp{\noexpand\MyCustomMacro{\BODY}}\temp`, but really hard to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of 'collecting the body' is nowadays available in `xparse`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\begin{document}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myEnv}{O{}+b}{The argument was '#2'}{}
\begin{myEnv}
  I first need to pass this to this environment as an argument.
\end{myEnv}
\end{document}
```

Here, `#2` is the second argument (the body).

As pointed out [in comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516754/how-to-pass-contents-of-environment-declared-with-newenvironment-in-latex2e-a#comment1306743_516754), the long-standing `environ` package does the same but provides the result as `\BODY`.

Comment: @bp2017 You need a more sophisticated loop to deal with spaces: there are several approaches (and examples on the site), depending on the other requirements (working by expansion, treatment of braces, ...). I'll adjust my answer to take `\par` tokens.

Comment: When I pass `\BODY` to `\zStart` as `\zStart{\BODY}` I don't get processed text, it's as if `\zStart` didn't work.

Comment: @bp2017 Well no, because there is only one token, `\BODY`. You'll need to expand it once: `\expandafter\zStart\expandafter{\BODY}`. TeX macros receive the tokens you pass _as written_, not the expansion of the tokens. I think that was mentioned in comments on the question.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464950/iterate-over-tokens for example